# Alias MySql em todas Colunas

Tags: mysql, mariadb, alias

Boa tarde Galera.

Estou com um probleminha pra juntar algumas tabelas por INNER JOIN, e devido ao nome das colunas serem iguais, imagino que o ALIAS pode me salvar alterando pro front o nome das colunas.

Acontece, que vou ter que fazer isso em diversas páginas e muitas colunas diferentes, é possível eu usar * do SELECT e pedindo pra usar Alias em todas colunas?

Algo como `SELECT * AS tabelarenomeada_* FROM tabela` para não ter que renomear coluna por coluna? Pois uma das querys que tenho como exemplo fica assim:

```
SELECT turmas.id AS turma_id, turmas.id_professor AS 
turma_idprofessor, turmas.id_curso AS turma_idcurso, 
turmas.data_inicio, turmas.qtd_alunos,
professores.id AS professor_id, professores.nome_professor AS 
professor_nome,
cursos.id AS curso_id
FROM turmas
INNER JOIN professores ON turmas.id_professor = professores.id 
INNER JOIN cursos ON turmas.id_curso = cursos.id 
WHERE turmas.ativo = 1 AND professores.ativo = 1 AND cursos.ativo = 1
```

Existe alguma maneira, de forçar todas as colunas a usar ALIAS com um nome fixo na frente do nome original por exemplo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá Rafael você pode definir um alias para as tabelas. Usando seu exemplo, faria da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT TUR.id AS turma_id,
       TUR.id_professor AS turma_idprofessor,
       TUR.id_curso AS turma_idcurso, 
       TUR.data_inicio,
       TUR.turmas.qtd_alunos,
       PROF.id AS professor_id,
       PROF.nome_professor AS professor_nome,
       CUR.id AS curso_id
   FROM turmas TUR
     INNER JOIN professores PROF ON TUR.id_professor = PROF.id 
     INNER JOIN cursos CUR ON TUR.id_curso = CUR.id 
  WHERE TUR.ativo = 1 AND PROF.ativo = 1 AND CUR.ativo = 1
```

Lembre-se que uma boa identação e a padronização do nome das tabelas e colunas facilita a manutenção e interpretação do código.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi o alias na tabela, mas acho que me expressei mal. O que eu gostaria, era de poder usar o * na busca mas de alguma forma renomear a coluna. Nesse caso vou usar muito `SELECT * FROM tabela1 INNER JOIN tabela2` por exemplo. Queria poder continuar usando o * sem precisar renomear coluna por coluna. Isso é possível? (Ah e desculpe a má identação, na hora de copiar o código veio mal formatado)

Comment: vc poderia definir assim `SELECT * FROM turmas tur INNER JOIN professores PROF ON TUR.id_professor = PROF.id INNER JOIN cursos CUR ON TUR.id_curso = CUR.id `

Comment: É possivel sim Rafael vc usar o * em um inner join... Quando você define `select coluna1, coluna2 from exemplo` vc restringe a busca apenas as colunas informadas... quando vc usa o *, todas as colunas da junção  da entre a tabela1 e a tabela2 serão retornadas.

Comment: Entendi, assim ficaria perfeita minha query, mas nesse caso, quando eu trouxer resultado pro FrontEnd o nome das colunas ainda será o original não? Pois meu problema é quando vou exibir isso em uma table HTML quando uso o id por exemplo, ele pode ser ambíguo, já que não renomeei para TUR.id como exemplo.

Comment: Nesse caso sim, o nome seria igual ao nome da coluna. Só que a maneira de passar o * não seria a mais correta. Por exemplo: aqui na empresa usamos o Protheus,seu BD tem tabela que possui mais de 100 colunas e os nomes das tabelas são parecido com este padrão `SB1010`, `SB5010`... Imagina só fazer uma consulta de produto trazendo todas as tabelas de `SB1010` junto com seu complemento de Produto `SB5010`... Iria alocar muito recurso na máquina além de trazer dados desnecessários a cada consulta...

Comment: A cada consulta, nós definimos as colunas e seus alias... Dá um pouco mais de trabalho mas facilita a manutenção do código e também é possível usar máscaras no alias da coluna dessa maneira: `select B1_COD as [Código], B1_DESC as [Descrição] from SB1010`

Comment: Isso é verdade. Podia virar mais dor de cabeça que solução. Muito obrigado pela ajuda e pelas dicas Leonardo. Me ajudou muito e esclareceu bastante também. Um abraço =]

Answer (score 1):

O problema maior que vejo na construção do select com o *:

Quando vc tem 1 tabela sem o uso do iiner join, o uso do * é válido.
Porém, veja que o inner join é pra incluir os campos da tabela professor e curso na tabela turma.
Mas se vc não colocar no select esses campos, os mesmos não vão aparecer na consulta.

Logo no select você tem que especificar quais os campos da tabela turma, professor e curso vc quer selecionar e ver depois de fazer a inclusão pelo inner join.

Uma forma que dá pra fazer é como mencionada de por aliás no nome da tabela também, dessa forma:

```
SELECT TUR.*,
       PROF.id AS professor_id,
       PROF.nome_professor AS professor_nome,
       CUR.id AS curso_id
   FROM turmas TUR
     INNER JOIN professores PROF ON TUR.id_professor = PROF.id 
     INNER JOIN cursos CUR ON TUR.id_curso = CUR.id 
  WHERE TUR.ativo = 1 AND PROF.ativo = 1 AND CUR.ativo = 1
```

Assim seleciona todos os campos da tabela turma e mais os especificos do inner join que é o professor e o curso.